# Pushing xml objects in to a array

Tags: php, xml, arrays

Okey so I am a bit confused about this. I have a xml that looks something like this:

```
<track>
<artist mbid="77cceea7-91bb-4a4c-ae41-bc9c46c1ccb5"> Red Hot Chili Peppers </artist>
<name> under the bridge </name>
<streamable>0</streamable>
<mbid/>
<album mbid="0fe94139-df63-4e51-b2e7-a1d53535cdd9">  Blood Sugar Sex Magik </album>
<url> http://xxxxxx.com </url>
<date uts="1351691244">31 Oct 2012, 13:47</date>
</track>
```

And I use simpleXML to parse the xml like this:

```
$artists = array();

$xml = simplexml_load_file("http://xxxxxxxxxxxxxx");

foreach($xml->recenttracks->track  as $track)
{
$artist = $track->artist;
    array_push($artists, $artist);
}  

var_dump($artists);
```

now I was hoping to get a nice array looking like this:

```
array(4) {
[0]=>
string(20) "Red Hot Chili Peppers "
[1]=>
string(20) "Red Hot Chili Peppers"
}
```

but what I am getting is something like this:

```
array(2) 
{ 
[0]=> object(SimpleXMLElement)#6 (2) { ["@attributes"]=> array(1) { ["mbid"]=> string(36) "8bfac288-ccc5-448d-9573-c33ea2aa5c30" } [0]=> string(21) "Red Hot Chili Peppers" } 
[1]=> object(SimpleXMLElement)#4 (2) { ["@attributes"]=> array(1) { ["mbid"]=> string(36) "8bfac288-ccc5-448d-9573-c33ea2aa5c30" } [0]=> string(21) "Red Hot Chili Peppers" } 
}
```

Now how do I get the artist only, not the whole SimpleXMLElement because I just can't figure it out.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The items you are adding to the array are `SimpleXMLElement`s. If you just want to add the string value, you must cast the `SimpleXMLElement` to a string.

```
$artists = array();
foreach($xml->recenttracks->track  as $track)
{
    $artists[] = (string) $track->artist;
}  

var_export($artists);
```

In general, you always want to cast `SimpleXMLElement` to a string when you want the string value. In some cases PHP will automatically coerce to string (for example when you `echo` it), but PHP type coercion rules are so complicated that it's better to always be explicit.

(Also, there is no need for `array_push()`, just use the bracket notation `$arrayname[] = $appendedvalue`.)

Answer (score 1):

The `var_dump` is giving you keys that you can use to access the different pieces, and casting to a string will give you just the node value, try:

```
$artist = (string) $track->artist[0];
```

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at these links... they've helped me in the past.

http://www.bookofzeus.com/articles/convert-simplexml-object-into-php-array/

http://milesj.me/blog/read/simplexml-to-array

Answer (score 0):

Try the below code.

```
$xml = simplexml_load_file("artist.xml");

echo $xml->artist;
```

Comment: if I just echo the artist I get the artist name only but if i push it in to the array I get all this extra information. forgot to mention that in the description.

Comment: @user1593846 - the confusion is that you didn't post the complete XML document, just one node. See my answer for how to access the value.